# How to use a the possessive "s" after a dot?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe, periods, saxon-genitive

How can I use an apostrophe to show possession after a dot?

Example: Martin Luther King **Jr.'s** world-view.

Is this correct?

Comment: +1 I have no idea. Other then Martin Luther King Junior's.

Comment: Dot's an easy question.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Why not. There's nowhere better to put it.

(Although some would cite this as a reason why we would be better off without the dot.)

Comment: Given that the English apostrophe-*s* is a fairly freely roaming clitic that can attach to the end not just of a word but of any noun phrase, I can’t see what could be so terribly wrong with just putting it where it goes. Try it with other proper-noun abbreviations like *Time Safari Inc.’s best customers*, for example, or *Sunset Blvd.’s main appeal*.

Answer (score 3):

The New Yorker has a convention of writing *Jr.,’s* in such cases, as in *Donald Trump, Jr.,’s love* ([source](http://www.newyorker.com/news/amy-davidson/donald-trump-jrs-love-for-russian-dirt)). It seems odd, but they present their rationale [here](http://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-correct-punctuation-of-donald-trump-jrs-name).